# Accidentally deleted /boot/efi / can't boot back into machine at all

Tags: partitioning

I had a dual booted machine with Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04. I was cleaning up some of the unneeded files in my Ubuntu space and like an idiot I used the rm -rf command with root privileges. This accidentally deleted by /boot/efi file and now I'm really screwed. At first I noticed none of the commands on terminal would work and the DE is a whole had become completely unresponsive. I tried restarting and it gave this image 
Boot error 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPavR.jpg)

After that I did a hard restart and open up boot menu, to see this 
Boot menu
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ltlfj.jpg)

Despite having grubx64efi as one of the options it doesn't recognize it and gives me the same error as before

If I check into the secure boot mode option of select UEFI as trusted for executing, it shows me the HDD0 disk on my system but when I click onto it I don't see anything

Is there anything I can do to fix this?
I have a windows recovery disk and a bootable USB for Ubuntu 18.04 if needed. I'm on an Acer Nitro AN-515-31 if that makes a difference

Comment: Seems you removed all boot-loaders from your Efi System Partition. Your Windows should be fine except it's missing it's boot-loader. How to reinstall Windows boot-loader is a Windows thing thus off-topic here. Your Ubuntu probably needs to be reinstalled, I think that faster than solving a 5000 pieces puzzle.

Comment: Is there anyway I can recover the data from my existing Ubuntu installation?

Comment: If you only deleted the files in /EFI/ubuntu or /EFI, then you can restore those files. Often best to also include those in backups in the future, but you can just reinstall grub and it will recreate them. You can use Boot-Repair from Ubuntu live installer to reinstall grub. Be sure to boot in UEFI mode as that will be how it repair it. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees, but you ought to be able to boot a live CD / live USB linux, mount partitions and sxport your data from there.